# Word 2007 xml image information

Tags: xml, xslt, office-2007, word-2007, wordml

I want to know the elements which store information regarding an image in a Word 2007 xml file. (such as height, width, visibility, etc.). In Word 2003 xml I could find it is shown as follows within v : shape tag.

```
<v:shape id="Picture 0" o:spid="_x0000_i1025" type="#_x0000_t75" alt="31.jpg" style="width:2in;height:95.85pt;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square">
<v:imagedata src="wordml://02000001.jpg" o:title="31"/>
</v:shape>
```

I couldn't find something similar in Word 2007 xml. Can someone tell me where I can find that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image size is stored where the graphic is being used (as you can use the same graphic multiple times at different sizes), in the a:graphic tag in line to where the image is being used. Instead of the data being here, like earlier, this now points to a relationship ID.

The list of relationships are in the top of the file, one of them you find will have a type of 'image'. 
The attributes of the Relationship will be the name of the target (such as media/image1.jpeg). This is a link to the binary of your image, and will be located later on in a pkg:part/pkg:binaryData element.

It looks a bit like this:

```
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
  <Relationship Id="rId8" Target="media/image1.jpeg" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" />
  .. other relationships
</Relationships>
.. lots more document

<pkg:part pkg:name="/word/media/image1.jpeg" pkg:contentType="image/jpeg"  pkg:compression="store">
    <pkg:binaryData>/9j/7QAsUGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA....blah
</pkg:part>
.. lots more document

<w:drawing>
 <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0">
   <wp:extent cx="2266950" cy="1543050"/>
    <wp:effectExtent l="19050" t="0" r="0" b="0"/>
    <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
    <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
     <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
       <a:blip r:embed="rId8" cstate="print"/>
       <a:ext cx="2266950" cy="1543050"/>
       .. lots more document
```

Comment: so, the image width and height attributes can not be found in the xml file, is that so? I need to access them from xsl. so that is not possible?

Comment: The image width and height values as displayed are available in 2007 in the same way they were in 2003, just in a different place. The values for width and height have always been the size of the display box (not necessarily the image). You can see in my reply, within the w:drawing//a:graphiData//pic:pic there is an a:ext (and wp:extent) which shows the size of the picture box, and there are other flags in the same area that show it to.